# Development about done time for production

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I have successfully set up my system using nodemcu .9 programmed using arduino ide. My setup is the wifi chip serially connected to synapses rf200p81. So I will need to power both chips and be able to program the esp8266.

I am going to need a hundred of these to start and more as time goes on. Should I just purchase the esp8266 12e alone and then purchase the parts necessary to power and program it and create my own pcb.

Or should I just use the nodemcu already assembled on a pcb with the rf200p81. Use the usb connection to program and then power the setup with vcc/gnd 3.3 volts.

I have not done this part before so I just don't know

Thanks Mark

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming, but electrical circuit design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have time and knowledge for development or know somebody who can do this for you, it would be, of course, cheaper to design your own PCB and buy just the parts you need.

There are companies that could handle for you buying parts, making/ordering a PCB, soldering everything and uploading a program to the devices. They usually provide a guarantee for their work.

Another advantage is that the device could be smaller than the ready PCB and that would be easier to make changes if necessary.

That approach however, is in case you have time and you're planning to scale your project in the future. If not, then just buy the already assembled PCBs. That way, you're sure that the electronic design is OK and you have the guarantee.

Check out regulations in your country as well. Additional electromagnetic tests might be needed if it's something more than a hobby project.

Comment: Ya I met with a guy that ended up being an independent contractor who subbed  out the work to a bay area pcb maker and he knew some assembly people.  Usually I avoid a 3rd party representative but he seemed ok.  We decided that the nodemcu 1.0 board (with the 12e) that I can get for under 3 bucks is the way to go.  I can't do anything with the synapses chip they are proprietary and I am stuck with them.  So I guess I am going to design a board that I can plug each chip/board into that has a power input.